# Google Maps API Polyline creation failing with "Uncaught TypeError: number is not a function"

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, django-templates, google-maps-markers, google-polyline

I'm working a django project using the google maps JS api.
Basically what's going on here is that I'm creating a map centered at a point (works perfectly), drawing a bunch of points specified by the `journey` variable (value is substituted in by django template),
and then trying to draw a polyine between these points. (Fails to produce a polyline with a "Uncaught TypeError: number is not a function" at the JS console.)

The traceback at the JS console is pretty indecipherable to me, particularly due to all the .js files being minned.

When I log the path attribute of the polyline, and the coordinate I'm adding (as seen below), everything seems to work. I know the coord is formatted correctly, because I think Marker and Polyline should take the same datatype (LatLng) for their locations, and the Markers work fine. Anyone have any idea what's happening?

```
var mapOptions = {
  center: { lat: 37.23112,
            lng: -122.29398
  },
  zoom: 15
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

// Make the line that will trace the guys route:
var polyOptions = {
  strokeColor: '#000000',
  srokeOpacity: 1.0,
  strokeWeight: 3
};
var poly = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
poly.setMap(map);

// Make an array of everywhere the lilguys has been. Passed into this django template as {"lat": 12, "lng": 8} objects.
var journey = [{"lat": 33.2389, "lng":-123.9349}, {"lat":32.928392, "lng":-122.29289}, {"lat":33.928982, "lng":-120.298392}];
var journey_markers = [];

// Draw all the placemarks
for (var i = 0; i < journey.length; i++) {
  var coord = journey[i];
  journey_markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({position: coord, map:map}));
  var path = poly.getPath();
  console.log(coord);
  console.log(path);
  path.push(coord);
}
```

Thank you!

EDIT:
I substituted the template variables in for what they evaluate to. This was checked by looking at the HTML source code in the browser, and confirmed to not be the source of the bug.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue, including the values required for  `{{ lilguy.current_lat }}`,`{{ lilguy.current_lon}}` and `{{ journey_coords|safe }}`

Comment: At a guess until you follow @geocodezip's suggestion, the values in journey_coords are strings instead of floating point numbers.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. The template variables were unnecessarily complicating things, as I could confirm their format by looking at the source code. I fixed the question.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the answer. It seems to be that unlike Markers, the Polyine path requires `google.maps.LatLng()` objects rather than latlng literals.
The following fixes the issue:

```
...
// Draw all the placemarks
for (var i = 0; i < journey.length; i++) {
  var coord = new google.maps.LatLng(journey[i].lat, journey[i].lng);
...
```